# Matching specific characters at any position in words

Tags: regex, pcre

How can I match words containing specific characters, say 'a' and 'r' at any position? E.g. in

`Maria xxx Paul xxx Taylor xxx Henry xxx`

the regex should match `Maria` and `Taylor` only.

Something like `\d.*[ar].*\b` doesn't work because that character class means 'a OR r', not 'a AND r'.

It seems to work with `(?i)\b\w*((?=r)\w*(?=a)|(?=a)\w*(?=r))\w*\b` but I wonder if there is a more efficient pattern?

I'm using an editor working with PCRE v8.36, no JavaScript. Thanks!

Comment: Why is this tagged `r`?

Comment: Yup, this tag is confusing. It is matching with the language R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following `RegEx` should accomplish your task:

```
[A-z]*[Aa][A-z]*[Rr][A-z]*|[A-z]*[Rr][A-z]*[Aa][A-z]*
```

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/vsQdzh/1) you can see a working example.

Comment: I've tested all proposals - this one is the most efficient solution regarding the steps it needs to achieve a match.

Thanks for each reply! And sorry for the wrong tagging. It was a typo - thanks to ExDev for correcting this.

Pym

Comment: @Pym Gordon: Happy to help, if it solved the problem, please [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) by clicking the checkmark at the left of the answer's text

Answer (score 0):

library `stringr` provides function `str_extract_all` for this. Used as shown below:

```
> string
[1] "Maria xxx Paul xxx Taylor xxx Henry xxx"

> str_extract_all(string, "[a-zA-Z]*a[a-zA-Z]*r[a-zA-Z]*")
[[1]]
[1] "Maria"  "Taylor"
```

Comment: Tag R might be a typo, see comments above.